# Difference between class and function blocks in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I was going through an article on **Commonly faced problems with React** and there i found this example.

```
class Numbers extends React.Component {
  const arrayOfNumbers = _.range(1, 10);
  // ...
}
```

It said "*The code above is invalid because inside the body of a JavaScript class you don’t have the freedom of doing just about anything. You can only define methods and properties using limited syntax.
This is a bit confusing because the {} used in the class syntax looks like the plain-old block scope, but it’s not.
Inside a function-based component, you DO have the freedom of doing just about anything*"

```
// Totally Okay:
const Number = (props) => {
  const arrayOfNumbers = _.range(1, 10);
  // ...
};
```

Can anyone explain to me why the above statement inside the class body is invalid ?? And what is that strange looking `_.` symbol ??

Comment: Well, it's simply a syntax error in a `class` body.

Comment: *"Can anyone explain to me why the above statement inside the class body is invalid ?"* Because class bodies can only contain method definitions. Just like object literals can only contain property definitions. You can [learn more about classes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class). *"And what is that strange looking `_.` symbol ?"* `_.range` accesses the property `range` on the value that the *variable* `_` resolves to. Another example: `var _ = {foo: 42}; console.log(_.foo);`.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling for the clarification

Comment: Why the down-vote though ??

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain to me why the above statement inside the class body is invalid ??

That's just the way the syntax for classes is. You can define functions in the body of the class, and they'll go on the prototype. If you want any instance variables, you do those in the constructor.

> And what is that strange looking _. symbol ??

It's a variable named `_`. In this case, it's almost certainly a reference to the [Lodash library](https://lodash.com/), a commonly used library with utility functions.